# Postgis disconnecting during some queries

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two tables one in SRID 4326 (containing `MULTIPOLYGON`) and the other in SRID 32188 (containing `MULTILINESTRING`).

I am trying to select all polygons from `t1` which are within 100 meters from any lines in `t2`.

This is the query I am making:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 
WHERE ST_DWithin(
        ST_Transform(t1.geom, 3857),
        ST_Transform(t2.geom, 3857),
        100);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and pgAdmin4 doesn't give me a useful error. Instead, it disconnects from the DB as soon as I run the query (so it's not a time out situation):

[image]

I also tried with two tables in the same SRID, but I still have the problem... What am I doing wrong here?

*EDIT*: In order to try an narrow down the problem, I took @JGH suggestion and adapted it to test ST_DWITHIN against a point instead of the multilinestrings of table2, and it works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM table2 t2
    WHERE ST_DWithin(t1.geom, ST_MakePoint(-73.63,45.52)::geography,100)
);
```

However, I tested with table2 containing only one straight line (still a multilinestrings geometry though), and the client crashes. Could it bee related to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31923/why-is-the-database-connection-lost-on-every-query ?

Comment: You should probably add the postgres  tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is probably timing out.

As it is, you are doing a cross-join between the two tables, so if a polygon from `t1` is within 100m of 10 features in `t2`, it will be returned 10 times. You likely want distinct polygons from `t1`. to do so, you would select only on `t1` and keep the row when the condition applied on `t2` is satisfied.

The second issue - which won't trigger any error unfortunately - is that it is wrong to compute distances using 3857. In Québec the length distortion is about 40%, which is huge. You would have to either use a suitable local projection (like MTM or UTM) for both geometries, or, if not possible, to cast to geography to do the distance computation.

And because you do transform both geometries to a new CRS, no spatial index solely on the geometries can be used and the distance computation will take a long, long time, causing your client to time out.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM table2 t2
   WHERE  ST_DWithin(t1.geom::geography, ST_Transform(t2.geom, 4326)::geography, 100)
   );
```

Don't forget to create a spatial index on the geography (and/or on the transformed geometry)

```
CREATE INDEX t1_geog ON t1 USING gist(geography(t1.geom);
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX t1_32188 ON t1 USING gist(st_transform(geom,32188));
```

Comment: It still disconnects, but thanks *a lot* for your advices! What I should have mentioned is that the client disconnects as soon as I run the query, so it's not a time-out situation :( I'll update my question to make this clear.

Comment: You can't get a detailed error message to the client over a connection that no longer exists, so you will have to look in the PostgreSQL server's log file to see what it says about the matter.